# How to obtain the product of the amplitudes of arbitrary basis vectors in a superposition state without measuring?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, swap-test, linear-algebra

Suppose there is a superposition state $|{{\Phi }^{+}}\rangle =\sum\limits_{i=0}^{15}{{{\alpha }_{i}}|i\rangle }$, I want to get ${{\alpha }_{i}}\times {{a}_{j}},i\ne j,i,j\in [0,15]$ without measurements. The swap test or Hadamard test is aimed at between two superposition states. Is it suitable for local inner product of superposition states? How can I explain my needs in terms of quantum circuits?

Comment: Is $\{|i\rangle\}$ an orthonormal basis? If so, the inner product is 0 for all $i\neq m$.

Comment: After thinking about it, I agree with your idea

Comment: What is $a_j$? What do you precisely mean by $\alpha_i \times a_j$?